# Affix scrollspy to top using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I'm trying to build a scrollspy similar to the one one the getboostrap website where the side navbar rises to the top of the page as you scroll, but then sticks to the top (http://getbootstrap.com/css/). I wrote a small script in my html to access the header size so that it would be compatible with different headers, but I want to move it into a separate javascript file. Here I'm including all of my html and the css for scrspy and affix.

HTML:

```
<div id="myScrollspy" role="complementary">

  <script>
    var element = document.getElementById('headerSize');
    document.write('<ul class="nav scrspy affix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="' +    element.offsetHeight + '" data-offset-bottom="200">');
  </script>

  <ul class="nav scrspy affix" data-spy="affix">
    <li class="active"><a href="#section-1">Section One</a></li>
    <ul class="nav scrspy">
      <li><a href="#section-1-1">Section 1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section-1-2">Section 1.2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#section-2">Section Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-3">Section Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-4">Section Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-5">Section Five</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section>
  <h2 id="section-1">Section One</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui.</p>

  <h2 id="section-1-1">Section 1.1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui.  

  <h2 id="section-1-2">Section 1.2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui.

  <h2 id="section-2">Section Two</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui.</p>

  <h2 id="section-3">Section Three</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui.</p>

  <h2 id="section-4">Section Four</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui.</p>

  <h2 id="section-5">Section Five</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui.</p>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.scrspy {
  > li {
    float: left;
    > a {
      color: @gray-dark;
      &:hover {
        border-right: 2px solid @blue;
      }
    }
  }
  .nav-stacked;
  .hidden-xs;
  .hidden-sm;
}
ul.scrspy, ul.scrspy ul li {
  width: 9.75rem;
}
ul.scrspy.affix {
  top: 1.85rem;
}
ul.scrspy ul li {
  padding: .315rem .47rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  font-size: @font-size-small;
}
ul.scrspy li.active a, ul.scrspy li.active a:hover {
  color: @daimler-blue;
  border-right: 2px solid @blue;
}
.affix {
  position: fixed;
}
ul.scrspy.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

I tried this in a separate .js file with a link to it in the html but it doesn't seem to work.
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var element = document.getElementById('headerSize');
  $('ul.scrspy').affix({
    offset: {
      top: element.offsetHeight
      bottom: 200
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What's the problem? Your description of the problem - "Doesn't seem to work" - is too vague.

Comment: I don't think it runs because nothing happens if I put an alert into the js. Right now the scrollspy is stuck on the top left corner of the page, on top of the content in the header.

Comment: What errors do you see in your JavaScript console?

Comment: By the way, left side is fine, it not using the offset is my problem.

Comment: It works now that I got rid of bottom:200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
<ul class="nav scrspy affix" id="stay" data-spy="affix">
```

to the html, and changed the javascript to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var element = document.getElementById('headerSize');
  $("#stay").affix({
    offset: {
      top: element.offsetHeight
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the css apart from `.sticky-top-affix` is for the demo.

Also note `data-top-add="20"` should be whatever `top` you set in that class to make it smooth. It is option - try not having it and see what happens.

```
.sticky-top-affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
}

body {
    height: 2000px;
}

nav {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
}

<p>Some stuff before the menu</p>
<p>Some stuff before the menu</p>
<p>Some stuff before the menu</p>
<p>Some stuff before the menu</p>
<p>Some stuff before the menu</p>

<nav class="sticky-top" data-top-add="20">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

var $stickyEls;

function onWindowScroll() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $stickyEls.each(function() {
       var $el = $(this),
           topOffset = $el.data('topOffset');
       $el[scrollTop >= topOffset ?
           'addClass' : 'removeClass']('sticky-top-affix');
    });
}

function stickyTopInit() {
    $stickyEls = $('.sticky-top');

    // Save positions.
    $stickyEls.each(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        var addToTop = +$el.attr('data-top-add') || 0;
        $el.data('topOffset', $el.offset().top - addToTop);
    });

    $(window).scroll(onWindowScroll);
}


$(document).ready(stickyTopInit);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3umh/

All we are doing here is saying "When you scroll passed the top of the menu add the `sticky-top-affix`, if you scroll before it remove it".